# gdb stops with too many watchpoints when there is only one

Tags: gdb

Do you know any other reasons why a watchpoint could not be inserted other than too many hardware breakpoints/watchpoints?

I have the following debug session:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1
...
(gdb) watch itrap_t_beg[1][222]
Hardware watchpoint 1: itrap_t_beg[1][222]
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
...
Hardware watchpoint 1: itrap_t_beg[1][222]

...
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
Warning:
Could not insert hardware watchpoint 1.
Could not insert hardware breakpoints:
You may have requested too many hardware breakpoints/watchpoints.

(gdb) info break
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       hw watchpoint  keep y                      itrap_t_beg[1][222]
        breakpoint already hit 1 time
```

As you can see, there's only one watchpoint yet it can't insert the breakpoint.

Do you know how can I fix this?

Comment: What's the type of objects in `itrap_t_beg` array?

Comment: Hi, it's a struct with 7 ints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gdb problem setting hardware watchpoint/how to set software watchpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470704/gdb-problem-setting-hardware-watchpoint-how-to-set-software-watchpoint)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as I know commodity x86 CPUs have four [debug registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register) available for supporting hardware breaks/watches. This limits the object size that you can watch. Object alignment also plays here.

Try limiting the watch scope to a smaller object like pair of first and last members of the structure.

Comment: Hey! It worked! Thanks. The strange thing is that I could set the first watch. Maybe, at that point, the itrap_t_beg was a char* and then it was casted to trap* (the source code is very old and things like that can happen). Thanks again!

Answer (score 15):

Can force software breakpoints (which do not have limit on size) by running

set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0

Comment: `Can't set read/access watchpoint when hardware watchpoints are disabled.` 

Answer (score 10):

Shot answer: Use `watch -location itrap_t_beg[1][222]`, or the short form `watch -l`.

Long answer: [Quoting the GDB manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html):

> Watching complex expressions that reference many variables can also exhaust the resources available for hardware-assisted watchpoints. That's because gdb needs to watch every variable in the expression with separately allocated resources.

gdb quite literally watches the expression itself, not whatever address it points to. In this case, it means that the breakpoint will hit if `itrap_t_beg` itself is changed such that `itrap_t_beg[1][222]` does; there's not just a watchpoint for `itrap_t_beg[1][222]`, but also one for `itrap_t_beg` itself. This may be more than what's available.

In your case, `itrap_t_beg` is 7 ints, 28 bytes. A x86_64 watchpoint is up to eight bytes, so GDB needs four watchpoints for the entire structure - plus a fifth for `itrap_t_beg` itself. The x86 family only supports four simultaneous watchpoints.

A more comprehensive example on how watchpoints work:

```
//set a watchpoint on '*p' before running
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int* p = &a;

int main()
{
    puts("Hi"); // Dummy lines to make the results clearer, watchpoints stop at the line after the change
    *p = 1; // Breaks: *p was changed from 0 to 1
    puts("Hi");
    a = 2; // Breaks: a is *p, which changed from 1 to 2
    puts("Hi");
    p = &b; // Breaks: p is now b, changing *p from 2 to 0
    puts("Hi");
    p = &c; // Doesn't break: while p changed, *p is still 0
    puts("Hi");
    p = NULL; // Breaks: *p is now unreadable
    puts("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

In theory, this is a useful feature; you can watch a complex expression, breaking as soon as it's false, somewhat like a constantly-tested assertion. For example, you can `watch a==b` in the above program.

In practice, it's unexpected, often triggers this issue, and usually isn't what you want.

To watch only the target address, use `watch -location itrap_t_beg[1][222]`. (This is available as of GDB 7.3, released in July 2011; if you're still on 7.1, use `print &itrap_t_beg[1][222]` and `watch *(itrap_t)0x12345678`, or whichever address it prints.)

Comment: This answer is mostly cross-posted from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206332/gdb-stops-with-too-many-watchpoints-when-there-is-only-one), since this is the top Google hit for "You may have requested too many hardware breakpoints/watchpoints."

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplica‌​te-answer-to-several-questions)