# Remove all hardware watchpoints in Linux kernel 3.0.0

Tags: linux, gdb, breakpoints, watchpoint

After setting the first (and only possible) hardware watchpoint via `watch varname` in GDB, it's not possible to remove it via delete.

Even if I just exit GDB, this watchpoint seems to be enabled till the next reboot. When I try to set another hardware watchpoint after GDB is restarted, a kernel message appears in logs telling me, all hardware watchpoints are already taken. It seems like it's the same problem as in *[Setting GDB hardware watchpoint/how to set software watchpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470704/gdb-problem-setting-hardware-watchpoint-how-to-set-software-watchpoint)*, but because I need a hardware watchpoint, the solution does not apply.

Is there a tool or a syscall to remove this (or all) hardware watchpoint? The CPU is an [Core i5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i5) and the Linux kernel is 3.0.0-17-generic from [Ubuntu 11.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_11.10_.28Oneiric_Ocelot.29) (Oneiric Ocelot).

Comment: This sounds like a bug. gdb uses ptrace to add/remove hardware breakpoints. So, you can try running gdb under strace and look for ptrace calls related to hardware breakpoints and hopefully, it should give you some clue about what's happening. Also, make sure you are running the latest kernel and gdb. Trying the upstream kernel is another option.

Comment: How do you try to remove it and what happens? Did you try latest gdb (7.4)?

Comment: Thanks for your help - I upgraded the kernel today to 3.0.0-19 and I'm now able to create more than one hardware watchpoint and they are automatically removed when gdb is closed.

Answer (score 13):

Use watchpoints (sometimes called data breakpoints). It can handle it as normal breakpoints, as follows:

```
(gdb) info watchpoints
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
2       acc watchpoint keep y                      x

(gdb) delete 2

(gdb) info watchpoints
No watchpoints.
(gdb)
```

A good reference is *[Setting Watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html#Set-Watchpoints)*.

Answer (score 2):

> After setting the first (and only possible) hardware watchpoint via watch varname in gdb it's not possible to remove it via delete.

The statement above is **false**. What led you to conclude it is true?

> Is there a tool or a syscall to remove this (or all) hardware watchpoint?

No such tool is necessary. Simply quit GDB, and all breakpoints and watchpoints will be gone. Or do `(gdb) delete` (without specifying a break point), and confirm that you want to delete all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to reproduce the behaviour. After the update to 3.0.0-19 today everything seems fine.