# gdb "watch pointer " giving too many h/w watchpoints error

Tags: c++, pointers, gdb

```
class Message{
    double *val
};

Message** val_msgs;
val_msgs = new Message*[120];
for(int i=0; i<120; i++)
    val_msgs[i]=new Message();
```

I am using gdb to watch a variable inside the *Message* data structure

```
watch val_msgs[0]->val
```

However, I get this error

```
(gdb) watch val_msgs[0]->val
Hardware watchpoint 2: this->val_msgs[0]->val
(gdb) c
Continuing.
pingCharmrun (ignored=0x7ffff73751c1) at machine.c:1151
1151    {
Current language:  auto; currently c
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Warning:
Could not insert hardware watchpoint 2.
Could not insert hardware breakpoints:
You may have requested too many hardware breakpoints/watchpoints.
```

As you can see I have set only 2 watchpoints.
Help, please?

Comment: I can't reproduce on GDB 8.1, Ubuntu 18.04 by adding a `main` to the test program given. Related threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206332/gdb-stops-with-too-many-watchpoints-when-there-is-only-one | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470704/setting-gdb-hardware-watchpoint-how-to-set-software-watchpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replies to this previous question may help: [gdb problem setting hardware watchpoint/how to set software watchpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470704/gdb-problem-setting-hardware-watchpoint-how-to-set-software-watchpoint)